# How to merge inner array with same key value

Tags: php, arrays

Please help to solve this issue
i want to change this

```
[UI Testing] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 70
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 40
                    [1] => 0
                )

        )
```

TO

```
[UI Testing] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 40
                    [1] => 70
                )

        )
```

Thanks.

Comment: Improve your question quality also share your efforts as in what all you've tried.

Comment: What kind of transform would you like to make?  Are you looking for maximum numbers in the same key?

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray[] = array(0,70);
$myArray[] = array(40,0);

$sumArray = array();

foreach ($myArray as $k=>$subArray) {
  foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {

    array_key_exists( $id, $sumArray ) ? $sumArray[$id] += $value : $sumArray[$id] = $value; 
  }
}

print_r($sumArray);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 40
    [1] => 70
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Array can be [**filtered**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove 0 valued indexes and [**array_reduce**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to merge array. An example below:

```
$arr = array('UI Testing' => array( array(0, 70), array(40, 0),) );

$new_arr['UI Testing'] = array_reduce($arr['UI Testing'], function($old, $new) {
    return array_filter($new, function( $v ){ return $v > 0 ? $v : null; }) + $old;
}, []);

print '<pre>';
print_r($new_arr);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [UI Testing] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40
            [1] => 70
        )
)
```